# Error: Package does not exist Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am a beginner Android developer.

I am busy walking through a code sample on DataBiding. I have the following Activity:

```
package com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.databinding.LoginActivityBinding;

import Common.Login;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LoginActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity);

        Login loginObject = new Login();
        loginObject.setEmail("test123@server.com");
        loginObject.setPassword("123456");

        binding.setLogin(loginObject);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use the LoginActivityBinding object, it imports the following package:

```
import com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.databinding.LoginActivityBinding;
```

After this, I get the following error:

> Error: package 'com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.databinding' does
>   not exist.

I agree that this package does not exist, but why does it try to import this package if it does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I forgot that I renamed my data variable used for binding.  My code was as follow:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="login"
        type="Common.Login"/>
</data>
```

And then I would try and bind as follow:

```
android:text="@{oldDataSourceName.password}"/>
```

Changing the above to point to my data variable name, fixed my problem, as follow:

```
android:text="@{login.password}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a layout named `login_activity.xml`. Android Data Binding automatically generates a Binding class based on the name of your layout XML file in the databinding package under your application's package. Since your application's package is `com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing`, and your layout is `login_activity.xml`, the generated class will be `com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.databinding.LoginActivity`.

I'm not sure why Android Studio is having difficulty. It could be that there is a cache problem or your removed the `<layout>` tags from the layout XML file. In any case, before you worry too much, try cleaning, compiling, and running it. Android Studio may just be confused and it may work anyway.

FYI, you can change the class name and/or package of the generated binding class. In the `<data>` tag, include the class name:

```
<layout xmlns:android="...">
    <data class="com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.LoginActivity">
        <variable .../>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout ...>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Android Studio adds the binding class to my package.  I do remember seeing a few folders/packages being added to my solution, but are no longer there, even after a clean/build.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here how it basically works, everything you type as an `import` statement, it tries to find that package/class to import it into your code so you can refer to it and its publicly available members and methods. So when you type `import com.example.andre.vehicleasseessing.databinding` of course it tries to import it into your code so you can start using it.

Comment: I believe the question was like this "I type LoginActivityBinding, it auto-completes and adds that import statement. That package does not exist."

Comment: I am not importing that package, when I try and use the LoginActivityBinding, it automatically creates that import statement.  LoginActivityBinding, according to Android tutorial, should be available if I use databinding

Comment: In Android and also in Java, in order to use some class that's not defined in your project, it has to be imported as an import statement, generall its package. So in order to use LoginActivityBinding, it should be defined either in your project (which mean you're writing your own version) or somewhere else right? There you go, it's importing that previously defined version by adding that import automatically, so you whenever you use that class the compiler knows where it refers to

Comment: Well, it does not exist, so where should that package point to?  Trust me, I have never tried to write my own version...

Comment: @monstertjie_za that's the automatic behaviour of IDE. I know you haven't written your own version. But what you must do is, explicitly add that package/project to your project, I suppose you missed some point in that tutorial where it adds that.

Comment: @OnurA. I will go back and check, lol.  Thanks for you efforts :-)

Comment: @monstertjie_za no worries :)